# Error in equation of performance prediction time

Tags: c, performance, architecture, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I have used this equation in order to obtain the execution time:

```
Execution time = Cpu time + memory time
```

then,

```
Execution time = (#instructions * average instruction execution time) +
                 (Misses Cache l1 * latency L2) +
                 (Misses Cache l2 * latency access memory).
```

I have develop a simple program in order to check this equation, the pseudo-code is the next:

```
  ini_time = get_cepu_time();
  Init_Papi_counters;

  //intesive computation code (matrix mult)

  End_Papi_counters();
  end_time = get_cepu_time();
  end_time = end_time - ini_time.
```

The values obtain are the next:

```
Execution time: 194,111 sec
Cycles: 568949490685
Instructions: 676850501790
Misses L1: 30666388828
Misses L2: 1743525419
```

The latencies obtain in the intel manual are:

```
Acces L2: 4,8 ns
Acces main memory: 110 ns
```

Then, If I apply the equation:

```
Misses L1 * Latency l2 = 147 sec
Misses L2 * memory access time =   193 sec
```

As we can see, the sum of the component of memory time is greater than the total execution time:

```
194 < 147 + 193 ERRORRRRR
```

Could you help me in order to discover how I can approximate the execution time.

Comment: The thing to know is that cache misses can overlap. A processor can handle multiple cache misses simultaneously. So the time taken up by cache misses is usually much less than (# of misses) * (miss latency). In any case, it's almost impossible to approximate the execution time other than to actually run it and time it. Modern processors are much more complicated than you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

How did you come up with these "equations"?  They are almost entirely incorrect for any modern CPU, which is why they produce garbage results.

> execution time = cpu time + memory time

All modern CPUs are capable of accessing memory *while computations are taking place*.  So there is significant overlap between these two measurements.  In addition, in any non-trivial environment, lots of other things that can happen that take measurable "execution time" -- stalling on disk access or network access, servicing interrupts, etc...

> Execution time = (#instructions * average instruction execution time) +
>                      (Misses Cache l1 * latency L2) +
>                      (Misses Cache l2 * latency access memory)

Setting aside cache misses, modern CPUs are pipelined and super-scalar; tens to hundreds of instructions are in flight simultaneously, and `instructions * average execution time` is far to simple of a model to capture the real complexity of the situation.  `instructions / (average instructions retired per time unit)` is a more accurate model, but still woefully inadequate for most usage, as the realized retire rate is extremely dependent on the specifics of the code being executed.

As Mystical noted in his comment, processors can service multiple cache misses simultaneously, so you can't simply account for them via a linear model either.  Except for the absolute simplest designs, modern CPUs are much to complex to be accurately described by any model of this form.  The only way to get accurate performance data is to actually run the computation on the part in question, or to use a cycle-accurate simulator that actually models all of the dependencies and resources involved in each stage of execution (there are very few modern CPUs for which such simulators are readily available, as they are very complex to do correctly).